# SpriteKit puzzle game

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite-kit, gamekit

The idea is to create module that will slice character on the pieces and then we can put all the pieces to theirs positions.

For example I have character on the canvas that has 1536 x 1536 px so I can simple down size it to all devices.

If you use photoshop here is a selections tools that can slice for me my character as I want.

I pick this way. Using selection tool I create regions with some colors that will represent for me pieces of the original image.

So the original image looks like this (thanks Matt Groening):
[image]

And the sliced one image looks like this (thanks Photoshop): [image]

So as you can see the colors repeat my selections that I did, my question how I can slice original image and extract all pieces with detection centers coordinates of all those pieces. Because I will need to put that pieces back from my side bar, because it's a puzzle game =)

I have written an algorithm that detect color of the pixel and start calculate borders of the piece. So for example when I cycle all pixels and detect one I rewrite min x, max x, min y and max y position of the selected color. For example on the image you see here are 4 colors and I try to find center of that colors on the layer. But here is big performance issue. For example if we cycle image with 1536 x 1536 px.

The second issue here it is Resampling. After we find coordinates in the biggest image (1536 x 1536), I try to scale image down to fit for example iPhone 4 size and scale down all found centers of all pieces.

And here is an resampling issue like on image below you can see extra transparent pixels at the junctions of colors:

[image]

Because I thin of linear of bicubic down sizing. Maybe I over thinking about it and idea how to slice image is more simpler.